# Projects disapper from NetBeans in Ubuntu after reboot

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, netbeans-8, mount, disk

I have recently shifted to Ubuntu from Windows

I am currently using **Ubuntu 14.04 Lts** and **NetBeans 8.2**.

I have created two partitions of my Hard disk.
here is a Screenshot of ***sudo fdisk -l***  [fdisk -l](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOV0X.png)

I like to create my **NetBeans** project on */dev/sda3* as it would be easy to maintain and manage Space.
But whenever i reboot my computer all the projects from /dev/sda3 disappear(not deleted) from projects tab in NetBeans but projects from */dev/sda1* exist.

*/dev/sda3* mount itself , i don't have to mount it manually, but i dont think it is mounted at boot(startup) time because i try to edit mount options in disk .[mount disk option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7DZx.png)

with this setting it gives me an error

> cannot mount the drive 7079a080-a6f5-41ee-93c8-675b352c77b8

please help me to solve this problem

Comment: I think it would be better to ask this question on https://askubuntu.com/